# angular2 typescript array of object filter by value

Tags: json, angular, typescript

I have an array getting data from JSON file. I am able to store an array of objects into my `Task[]`. Now I want to retrieve the data by status ('Submitted' or 'Resolved' etc). I tried many ways, but unable to achieve it. Please help me.

```js
data: [{
  taskname: 'Test1',
  taskId: '1',
  status: 'Submitted'
}, {
  taskname: 'Test2',
  taskId: '2',
  status: 'Resolved'
}, {
  taskname: 'Test3',
  taskId: '4',
  status: 'Submitted'
}, {
  taskname: 'Test4',
  taskId: '5',
  status: 'In Progress'
}, {
  taskname: 'Test5',
  taskId: '6',
  status: 'Resolved'
}, {
  taskname: 'Test6',
  taskId: '7',
  status: 'Submitted'
}
}]
```

Task.ts

```js
export interface Task {
  taskId: any;
  taskname: any;
  status: any;
}
```

taskService.ts

```js
getTask() {
  return this.http.get('../app/common/task.json')
    .toPromise()
    .then(res => < Task[] > res.json().data)
    .then(data => {
      return data;
    });

}
```

taskCompnent.ts

```js
export class TaskComponent implements OnInit {
  taskList: Task[];
  datasource: Task[];
  sortedList: Task[];
  ngOnInit() {
    this.taskService.getTask().then(files => this.files = files);
    this.vecService.getData().then(taskList => {
      this.datasource = taskList;
      this.taskList = this.datasource; // Storing data into my task list array
    });
  }
}
```

This is what I tried to filter by status:

```
 this.sortedList = this.taskList.filter(
      task => task.status ==='Submitted');
```

showing error below error:

> Cannot read property 'filter' of undefined

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why is my variable unaltered after I modify it inside of a function? - Asynchronous code reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23667086/why-is-my-variable-unaltered-after-i-modify-it-inside-of-a-function-asynchron)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's because promises / HTTP requests are asynchronous. You need to add filter  within the callback of the promises, if you place it outside taskList will be undefined so the filter cannot be applied

```
this.vecService.getData().then(taskList => {
        this.datasource = taskList;
        this.taskList = this.datasource;// Storing data into my task list array
        this.sortedList = this.taskList.filter(
        task => task.status ==='Submitted');

    });
```

Comment: Thanks Sajeetharan, Since two hours trying out side of the callback of promises. Thank you so much.